# I receive ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED when I call mDisplay.getOrientation

Tags: android, configuration

I want to retrieve my device orientation and when I call  mDisplay.getOrientation I receive ORIENTATION , how can I get the orientation in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation below the method getOrientation has been deprecated.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getOrientation()

Try using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation(), this should return the angle which the device has been rotated.